# Replace div content from another div without server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am currently working on my personal website. I had a vertical nav on the left side. When I click on a link from the nav I would want to replace the div content with another div from another html file (I could copy and paste the nav code on all my html pages but that wouldn't be efficient).

I tried the .load() but I believe I need to use a server. For a basic site of replacing content from other html pages, how can I achieve this?

ex.

index.html file

```
<li><a href="javascript:display_blogs()">Blogs</a></li>
...
<div id="content"></div>
```

blogs.html file

```
<div id="GETBLOG">I am a blog.</div>
```

app.js file

```
function display_blogs() {

  $('#content').load("blogs.html #GETBLOG");
}
```

So when the user clicks on "BLOGS" link, It should display I am a blog in the "content" div.

I need an alternative because I think .load can only be used in a server. I want to do this without a server if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the question exactly. Do you want the content to change with loading a new page or without loading (changing) pages?

Comment: Missing a *hash* in: `$('content').load`, should be `$('#content').load`

Comment: First things first change `$('content').load("blogs.html #GETBLOG");` to `$('#content').load("./blogs.html");` otherwise you aren't telling it where to load to as $('content') won't select any element.  Check the request of the load in your network traffic to see if it properly fetches (url is what you expect, etc).

Comment: I want to change the contents in a div which is in the same html page (I added the missing hash).

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery:
`$('tagName').load( url,[data],[callback] );`
Make sure to replace `tagName` with what ever tag name you need.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Do I have to use a server in order to use the .load? Because I'm not trying to use a server for a basic site.

Comment: I wouldn't think so.

Comment: I mean you won't need a server to use .load

Comment: Although please note that I am not incredibly experienced in jQuery and this could very well be the wrong answer. :-)

Comment: Even though I'm not experienced in jQuery, I still don't think you will need a server.

Comment: I just tested it with a server running and it worked. So .load can only be used with a server running.

Comment: Oh, well. Dang it. :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#pageContent").load('pages/page1.html #divid2load');
// will load the #divid2load div from the html page.
```

Comment: I am trying to do it without a server. I think .load is using a server.

Comment: Ok I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

If you make an AJAX call to one of your HTML files you'll get that file's content.

So one approach would be to break your content into partials and load them wherever they're needed as they're needed.

Alternatively, you could get the file and then parse through it for the content you want, for example getting the content in `#GETBLOG`

Comment: No need to *break the content into partials*, as this is exactly what the second parameter in [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) does. the second param tells what page fragment of the remote document should to be inserted.

Comment: Well AJAX requires a server. I am trying to do this with javascript and nos server if possible.

Comment: AJAX doesn't require an external server, pass it the file route.

Comment: @BrandonBrickyKerr , Are you sure? Can you access local files with AJAX not using an outdated browser?

Answer (score 0):

API: `.replaceWith` http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Example:

```
$('#div2').replaceWith($('#div1').html());​
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/M4v4M/

or

```
$('#div2').html($('#div1').html());
```

Comment: The problem is both the divs are in the same html page. I need to replace div from page2.html to page1.html.

Comment: Then `.load` is the way to go but this is equivalent to `.get` so you are doing AJAX request to the server anyway as the server needs to serve other page - you need to obtain data from page2.html.

Comment: I realized what I wanted to do is going to require a server. I guess I'll have to do it that way. I can't seem to find a way to replace div from an external html file without using a server such as using jQuery .load().